# How to create json array and insert json object

Tags: json, go

How to create a json array and insert json objects into it?
I have a for loop. And in that for loop I'm able to generate a json object. I want to store this in the json array.

```
for i := 9; i <= 10; i++ {
    var obj map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{}"), &obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    obj["key1"] = "val1"
    obj["key2"] = "val2"
    // Here i want to add this json(obj) into an array
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried in the question. It depends on what is the structure of your json objext to be stored inside an array or slice or slice of structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do

```
var arr []interface{}
```

and append the object to it

```
arr = append(arr, jsonObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.

We can use an array of interfaces.

```
var jsonArr []interface{}
```

and append to it.

```
var obj map[string]interface{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{}"), &obj)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
   return
}
obj["key1"] = "val1"
obj["key2"] = "val2"
jsonArr = append(jsonArr, obj) // obj is the jsonObject
```

Marshal it

```
jsonArrVal, _ := json.Marshal(jsonArr)
fmt.Println(string(jsonArrVal))
```